# Mysqli query with a SET variable statment (ie multiple queries)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysqli

I want to set a variable to use in a mysqli query.  This doesn't quite work.  Prior to mysqli I used to set query calls.  I played around with db->multi_query($sql) with no luck.  Anyone out there have an idea how to make this work including a set statement?

```
$sql = 'SET @rownum := 0;';
$sql .= 'SELECT @rownum :=@rownum + 1 AS Rank, User_Id, COUNT(User_ID) AS Block_Count
               FROM Block_Owners;

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $world, $userId);
// execute the query
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You might be able to perform that within a single query using `FROM BLOCK_OWNERS, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it in two separate queries:

```
$db->query('SET @rownum := 0');
$sql = 'SELECT @rownum :=@rownum + 1 AS Rank, User_Id, COUNT(User_ID) AS Block_Count FROM Block_Owners'
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $world, $userId);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note, however, that the query you want to run will always return a single row (with `Rank = 1`) since you are using an aggregate function without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Perfect.  No worries on the group by, the actual query is bigger, I just simplified it a bit to make the question easier to understand.  Thanks Quassnoi!