# Combine LIKE and IN in PHP MySQLi prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Trying to build a searchpage for an equipment database, and I have a prepared statement which takes an equipment 'tag' (always required) and searches a keyword in six different data fields where the 'tag' matches user input.

The problem is that no results are found if the keyword is `IN` one of these possibly long fields, so many intended results are missing.

In regular SQL I'd just to a table join and add a `LIKE` query to an `IN` query; but with mysqli I'm using a prepared statement with the `?` placeholder and not sure what can be done about using this mark more than once for each variable.

The statement I have is this:

```
if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM equipment 
    WHERE EQUIP_CND LIKE ? 
    AND (EQUIP_TYP LIKE ? OR ((EQUIP_SER LIKE ? OR EQUIP_PNO LIKE ?) 
        OR (EQUIP_LOC LIKE ? OR EQUIP_CMT LIKE ?)));"))) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}
```

And I want to just replace `LIKE` with `LIKE IN`. How to achieve this?

Comment: You don't need all those nested parentheses. Just `AND (x LIKE ? OR y LIKE ? OR z LIKE ? ...)`

Comment: What do you mean by "if the keyword is IN one of these long fields"? Are they comma-separated lists?

Comment: Why do you think you can't do a `JOIN` in a prepared statement?

Comment: No probem about binding a var more than once, you just ned to repeat it for evary placeholder in the bin_param arguments. but you could also use a variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773812/mysqli-query-with-a-set-variable-statment-ie-multiple-queries

Comment: Prepared statements are the same as a regular query the driver just handles the quoting and escaping. Every `?` is a value, so bind the same number of variables as you have `?`s. Append wildcards to the variables as needed. I don't know what `LIKE IN` would be, can you explain that or show sample data of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Barmar with regard to your second comment, I have six fields which are long `varchar` type fields. One of them is a comment / note section, so I'm for example searching for the word 'tested' and getting no result if the comment field is 'Refitted and tested in April'.

Comment: The variable that you bind to all the `?` should have the value `%tested%` so that `LIKE` will search for the word anywhere in the fields.

Comment: @Barmar , that last comment solved the issue perfectly. I had clearly not understood the behavior of the `LIKE` statement. Thanks!

Comment: @user2727391 There also is full text matching which might perform better for you. You can search multiple columns at once. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `like` requires `wildcards` to have loose matching.

e.g.

```
select * from table where a like 'b'
```

is the same as:

```
select * from table where a = 'b'
```

so a record of `b` would be found but `abc` would not.

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

> With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:
>
> **%** matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
>
> **_** matches exactly one character.

So to find `abc` you'd use:

```
select * from table where a like '%b%'
```

For prepared statements the wildcards get appended to the variable, or in the binding, NOT in the query itself. Example 6 on the PDO manual page shows this. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-991 (after the comment `// placeholder must be used in the place of the whole value`)